# How do you work out the matrix for controlled-U operations?

Tags: quantum-gate, linear-algebra, quantum-operation

I see this equations all over for controlled-U operations:

$$
\left|{0}\right>\left<{0}\right| \otimes \mathbf{1} + \left|{1}\right>\left<{1}\right|\otimes U
= \begin{pmatrix}
\mathbb{1} & 0 \\
0          & U
\end{pmatrix}
$$

I have been trying to work this out and can not figure out where I'm going wrong:

$$
\begin{align}
\left|{0}\right>\left<{0}\right| \otimes \mathbf{1} + \left|{1}\right>\left<{1}\right|\otimes U
&= \begin{pmatrix} 0 \\ 0 \end{pmatrix}\begin{pmatrix} 0 & 0 \end{pmatrix}
\otimes \begin{pmatrix}
1 & 0 \\
0 & 1
\end{pmatrix}
+ \begin{pmatrix} 1 \\ 1 \end{pmatrix}\begin{pmatrix} 1 & 1 \end{pmatrix} \otimes U\\
&= \begin{pmatrix}
0 & 0 \\
0 & 0
\end{pmatrix}
\otimes\begin{pmatrix}
1 & 0 \\
0 & 1
\end{pmatrix}
+ \begin{pmatrix}
1 & 1 \\
1 & 1
\end{pmatrix} \otimes U \\
&= \begin{pmatrix}
0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & 0 & 0
\end{pmatrix}
+ \begin{pmatrix}
U & U \\
U & U
\end{pmatrix} \\
&= \begin{pmatrix}
U & U \\
U & U
\end{pmatrix}
\neq \begin{pmatrix}
\mathbb{1} & 0 \\
0          & U
\end{pmatrix}
\end{align}
$$

Even checking with python doing the calculations, I get the wrong answer. Where am I going wrong? Or can someone explain what I'm missing?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

$\left|0\right>$ and $\left|1\right>$ don't mean $\begin{pmatrix}0 \\ 0\end{pmatrix}$ and $\begin{pmatrix}1 \\ 1\end{pmatrix}$.

In bra-ket notation we usually fix some basis and denote by $\left|a\right>$ the element of this basis labeled by the symbol $a$. In the case of a qubit $\left|0\right>$ and $\left|1\right>$ denote the basis vectors $\begin{pmatrix} 1 \\ 0 \end{pmatrix}$ and $\begin{pmatrix}0 \\ 1\end{pmatrix}$

Comment: I... Thank you.